# Material UI: Menu refactoring

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

was trying to refactor my menu, which uses List from Material UI.

The unrefactored menu looks like this

```
    <SelectableList id="menu" value={location}>
    <ListItem primaryText="Encoding" primaryTogglesNestedList={true} value="/encoding" nestedItems={[
        <ListItem primaryText="Base32" containerElement={<Link to="/base32"/>} value="/base32"/>,
        <ListItem primaryText="Base32Hex" containerElement={<Link to="/base32Hex"/>} value="/base32Hex"/>,
        <ListItem primaryText="Base64" containerElement={<Link to="/base64"/>} value="/base64"/>,
```

and there is clearly a lot of boilerplate, so I decided to create a custom component, which would handle the duplicities in the code

```
import React from 'react';
import {ListItem} from 'material-ui/List'
import {Link} from 'react-router'

const MenuItem = ({anchor, ...other}) => (
    <ListItem containerElement={<Link to={anchor} />} value={anchor} {...other} key={"item-"+ anchor}/>
);


export default MenuItem;
```

The problem is, that when I used it

```
<MenuItem primaryText="Base32" anchor="/base32" />
```

The menuItem ceased to be selectable. Further more, to recall the value from *SelectableList id="menu" value={location}* (to expand the menu, when page is reloaded), I had to to add value tag to MenuItem as well (duplicity back).

How should I handle this refactoring?

---

**Update**
JSFiddle (simplified example): https://jsfiddle.net/1vk8wzoc/27/

Comment: Can you post a codepen or something please?

Comment: Good point, https://jsfiddle.net/1vk8wzoc/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so looking at your JSFiddle and the Material UI source, it seems like they reject children without certain properties:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/List/makeSelectable.js#L18

```
extendChild(child, styles, selectedItemStyle) {
  if (child && child.type && child.type.muiName === 'ListItem') {
    ....
```

So your component is never receive the styles to indicate that its selected.

I would do one of two things here:

1. Possibly raise a PR with the library to support HOC's for
   Listitems
2. Or, use `React.cloneElement` which *should* copy all
   the required stuff across so it appears to be the right element to
   the `makeSelectable` function

Comment: Thanks very much, I raised a ticket in GitHub of material UI (https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/6263).